# Accessing a copy of of a struct. I get the error: request for member ‘count’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, pointers, struct

For some reason I am not able to access procNames.count. All I need to do is increment the counter. I am not sure why. Anyone sees the problem?

```
struct config_line {
    char name[MAX_WORD];
    int time;
};

struct config {
    struct config_line *lines;
    int count;
};

//global variable
struct config configData;

// allocate memory to procNames
procNames = malloc(sizeof(struct config));
if ( procNames == NULL ) {
    printf("problem allocating memory, for procNames. int procnanny(void)");
    return 0;       
}
//local variable
struct config *procNames;

procNames = &configData;
// the problem
procNames.count++;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
procNames->count++;
```

`procNames` is a pointer, so you need to use that or the long-winded:

```
(*procNames).count++;
```

You can only use the `.` operator when the value on the LHS is a structure.  When you have a pointer to a structure, you have to either use `->` or dereference the pointer and then apply the `.` operator, which requires parentheses as well as the `*` because `.` binds tighter than unary (dereferencing) `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Should it be

```
procNames->count++
```